# Flash is not displayed in IE8 (in ASP.NET MVC application )

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash

Here is my code in Site.master

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
                        width="980" height="337" id="flashheader" align="middle">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                        <param name="movie" value="header.swf" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                        <embed src="../../Content/flash/header.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="980"
                            height="337" name="header" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="false"
                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                    </object>
```

it is inside div (i've read somewhere that width should be defined for IE)

```
#header
{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('designimages/header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

also i tryed:

It is simple animation, and it works ok in Firefox and Chrome. What could be wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong path to your movie in the  param?

```
                   <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
                        width="980" height="337" id="flashheader" align="middle">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                        <param name="movie" value="../../Content/flash/header.swf" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                        <embed src="../../Content/flash/header.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="980"
                            height="337" name="header" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="false"
                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
                    </object>
```